# When you zoom in with a lens on an SLR why does the lens go in then out?

Tags: lens, zoom, optics, lens-design

I guess this is more a question of optics than photography but I just got an SLR with a basic 18-55 lens.  I noticed that when going from 18 to 55 or 55 to 18 the lens physically comes back in and then physically goes back out?

What is going on there?  I would think that if I am zooming in the lens should be going out 100% of the time but the lens actually goes out and then comes back in.

Comment: @mattdm Both of the existing answers are correct -- it depends on the lens. That's why both seem plausible. A zoom that has a shorter focal length at any point than the flange-to-sensor distance must be retrofocal. By the same token, if the optical center is closer to the center than the apparent focal length at any point, it must be telephoto. Some lenses are both, depending on the focal length setting. The Nikon 18-200 must be retro at 18mm, but is only 162mm long fully extended. Add the flange distance, then account for the location of the optical center of the lens: it's telephoto. QED

Comment: Could you please take the lens out of the body, look at the rearmost element, and tell us how it moves when you zoom from 18 to 55 mm?

Comment: As I understand DragonLord's answer, the explanation is that retrofocal lenses increase in extension as they zoom _out_, and telephoto lenses increase in extension as they zoom _in_, and that this type of lens crosses between the two. Edgar Bonet's answer says that this "switchover" of direction of lens extension happens _even with completely retrofocal designs_, and that if the lens happens to also be telephoto when zoomed in far enough, that's incidental. Which of these is true?

Comment: @EdgarBonet -- the movement of the rear and front) element alone is not sufficient to make a determination either way for a particular lens; you'd need to take the lens down to groups and helicoids to be sure if the design isn't published.

Comment: @Zach: can you un-accept DragonLord's answer as per his request? See below....

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have switched the correct answer.  Thanks for all the great discussion!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is no simple relationship between the physical length of the lens
and its focal length. For example, a retrofocus wide angle is generally
longer than its focal length, while a telephoto lens is shorter than
its focal length. Inside a zoom, you have several lens groups that move
independently. The focal length of the zoom depends on the *relative*
positions of the groups, and is not always simply related to the
physical length of the lens. That being said, the *simplest* possible
explanation for this behavior is that your zoom may be of a simple
retrofocus design.

### Retrofocus zoom

A [retrofocus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ang%C3%A9nieux_retrofocus)
zoom is made of only two groups. The front group, of negative refractive
power and (negative) focal distance *f*<sub>1</sub>, makes a virtual
intermediate image of the object somewhere in front of the lens. This
group works much like the glasses short-sighted people wear: it brings
the object “closer to the eye”. The focal length of this group is close
to -35 mm.

The rear group, of positive refractive power, makes on the sensor an
inverted real image of this intermediate virtual image. The intermediate
image is the “object” for this group. The final image is like an
inverted copy of the virtual image, scaled by a magnification factor
*m*<sub>2</sub> close to -1, which is negative because the final image
is inverted.

Assuming the object is at infinity, the whole lens has a focal length
*f* = *f*<sub>1</sub>×*m*<sub>2</sub>. This is a product of two negative
numbers, and the result is positive.

[image: retrofocus lens]

In the above simplified drawing, the first group is the lens L1, the
second group is the lens L2, the zoom is focused at infinity, the
intermediate image is at the left, at a distance *x* from L2, and the
sensor is at P. The magnification of L2 is *m*<sub>2</sub>=-*x*’/*x*.

With this design, it is easy to zoom the lens by moving the second
group. When this group is closer to the sensor, it provides a small
magnification (say around -0.5) and thus a shorter focal length for the
whole lens. When it is moved forward, closer to the intermediate image,
you have higher magnification (say around -1.6) and thus a longer focal
length for the whole lens.

However, as you change the magnification of this group, the distance
between the object (in this case the intermediate image) and the final
image changes. This distance is at a minimum when the group is just in
between its object and its image, which happens when the magnification
is -1. You can check this easily by using a magnifying glass to focus
the image of a lightbulb on a piece of paper: the distance between the
the bulb and the focused image is minimal when the image has the same
size as the object. In the case of the zoom lens, since the final image
has to fall at a fixed position (on the sensor), the intermediate image
has to be moved by moving the front group. This explains the observed
behavior of the front group: as you zoom the lens from 18 mm to ~35 mm,
the magnification *m*<sub>2</sub> goes from ~-0.5 to -1 and the front
group moves closer to the sensor. As you zoom from there to 55 mm,
*m*<sub>2</sub> goes from -1 to ~-1.6 and the front group moves away
from the sensor.

### Example 1

This is just a theoretical (over)simplified model for a zoom where each
group is just a thin lens. The focal lengths of the groups are -35 mm
(front group) and +35 mm (rear group). Assuming an object at infinity, I
calculated the configurations of the zoom for three focal lengths. The
table below shows the positions of the lens elements (in mm from the
sensor) as a function of the focal length the zoom is set to:

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ f. length │ group 1 │ group 2 │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│   18 mm   │  121.1  │    53   │
│   35 mm   │  105    │    70   │
│   55 mm   │  112.3  │    90   │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

And here is a drawing, to scale:

[image: zoom at 18, 35 and 55 mm]

The sensor is at the right. The intermediate image (not drawn) is 35 mm
to the left of the front element. The interesting thing is that the
movements of the groups (both front and rear) match what I've seen on
most small mid-range zooms. A real zoom may have more groups (IS has
been mentioned), but only two are really needed for the zoom action.

### Example 2

For a more realistic example, see this
[patent for some Nikon 1 zooms](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/20110116172.pdf).
It's not the best example because these lenses are intended for a
mirrorless camera. However, one of the embodiments is a 10-30 mm
midrange zoom (27-81 equiv.), quite close in range to a 18-55 for 1.6×.

I like this example though because of the figures.
Please take a look at the figure on page 1, and more specifically at the
arrows at the bottom, below the labels “G1” and “G2”. These arrows show
the way the groups move when the lens is zoomed from wide (W) to tele
(T). You can see that the front group moves back and then forward, while
the second group moves monotonously forward. That's what I have seen on
many wide and midrange zooms, although not on all of them (not on the
Nikkor 18-70 for example). You may notice that the second group has some
subgroups among it, including one group for focusing (Gf) and one group
for image stabilization (Gs). These subgroups are however irrelevant
when one considers *only* the zooming action.

Anyway, the interesting thing here is that, although some of the provided
examples have three lens groups, most (including the “preferred
embodiment”) only have two. Quoting the patent (paragraph 077 on page 67):

> An optical system according to the present embodiment includes, in
>   order from an object side, a first lens group having negative
>   refractive power, and a second lens group having positive refractive
>   power.

This is exactly the description of a retrofocus lens.

### Example 3

Here is
[another patent from Nikon](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/20110109977.pdf)
which may be more relevant since it mostly describes the 18-55 kind of
APS-C zooms.

Examples 1 and 2 of this patent are for such a simple retrofocus design,
with a front group of focal length -31.51 mm and a rear group of focal
length +37.95 mm. From the data tables we see that, as you zoom the
lens from 18 to 55 mm, the front group moves first back (towards the
sensor) and then forward (away from the sensor) while the rear group
moves monotonously forward.

This patent shows also that the simple two-group design I am describing
here is not the only possible option. Consider the example 5 of this
patent. This lens has four groups that move all in different ways as the
lens is zoomed. When zooming from 18 to 55 mm, the front group moves
back, then forward, and the rear group moves monotonously forward. Thus,
as seen from the outside, it *looks* like the simple two-group design of
example 1, although internally it is quite more complex.

On the other hand, this particular design is actually *not that far*
from the simple retrofocus design. If we say that groups 2, 3 and 4
constitute a sort of “super-group”, then the lens can be described as a
group (G1) of negative refractive power followed by the super-group
(G234) of positive refractive power. Still kind of a retrofocus. This
description is not completely unreasonable as groups 2, 3 and 4 move
more or less in the same fashion: they all move monotonously forward as
the lens is zoomed from wide to tele, and their average movement is
greater than the relative movements between them. From the table of lens
data I calculated the focal length of this super-group and found that it
does not change a lot: only from 38.6 mm at the wide end of the zoom to
34.8 mm at the tele end.

Although I have only investigated a few patents, my conclusion is that
some sort of retrofocus design (but not necessarily with only two
groups) is likely on a zoom if the following three conditions are met:

- the lens is longer than its focal length at all settings
- when zoomed from wide to tele, the front element moves first back
  (closer to the sensor), and then forward
- when zoomed from wide to tele, the rear element moves always forward.

The first condition is likely to be always met by SLR zooms having a
maximum focal length of no more than 55 mm.

**PS:** This answer has been heavily edited in order to better merge
several edits. In the process I incorporated an important point raised
by Stan Rogers, namely that the simple design is not the only possible
design.

Comment: Can you explain in very simple language why this makes a typical 18-55 lens start at middle length, then decrease, and then increase?

Comment: Because, with a converging group, the distance between the object and the image is minimum when the magnification is -1. Thus, starting at low magnification, as the magnification increases the distance first decreases and then increases again.

Comment: And, while I hate to ask you I prove a negative, since the accepted answer and wikipedia article both include the idea that the function of the front group shifts from negative to positive, could you elaborate on that a bit more? It'd be particularly nice to show how this works with a typical 18-55mm. And, how _would_ a lens with the tele/retro design behave w.r.t. lens extension?

Comment: @mattdm: a magnification of -1 means that the image has the same size as the object, but is reversed. In macrophotography one would instead say “1:1”, forgetting the sign. And it's not “-1 something”, as magnifications have no units. By “zooming in (resp. out)” I mean turning the zoom ring towards longer (resp. shorter) focal lengths.

Comment: @DragonLord: If you define a telephoto that way, then you have to measure the length of the lens from the front element to the image plane. In this example the length defined this way is 112.3 mm.

Comment: @Edgar, just to confirm my understanding: with this explanation, the front element is _always_ divergent, with a -35mm focal length, regardless of zoom position, right? With the other explanation, this front group (or several front groups) would change in focal length as the lens zooms?

Comment: PS: Although you wouldn't _have_ to do this by any stretch, it'd be awesome if you could go through your updates and coalesce them into one single coherent answer.

Comment: Note that the Canon 18-55 has five independent groups: http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/data/ef-s/ef_s18-55_35-56_is_ii.html?p=2

Answer (score 10):

**See edit note below this answer.**

---

<s>The lens is retrofocal at the wide end and telephoto at the long end.  A retrofocus lens is referred to as "inverted telephoto" because it is constructed similarly to a telephoto lens with the elements reversed.  The effect decreases as you zoom in, until you reach about 35mm, at which the lens begins to extend and eventually becomes a telephoto configuration, where the size of the lens, front element to rear element, is less than the focal length.  The lens is neither retrofocal nor telephoto between these positions.  This results in the lens being longer at the extremes of the zoom range than at intermediate positions.</s>

For more information on this design, see the Wikipedia articles on [Angénieux retrofocus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ang%C3%A9nieux_retrofocus), which discusses the origin of the design for the wide end, and [telephoto lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephoto_lens) for what happens at the long end.  According to the telephoto lens article:

> Zoom lenses that are telephotos at one extreme of the zoom range and retrofocus at the other are now common.

This is essentially what is happening with your 18-55mm lens.  As far as I am aware, Canon, Nikon, Pentax, and Sony (A-mount, not E-mount) 18-55mm lenses all share this
design aspect.

---

**Edit:** This answer is incorrect because it is based on an incorrect definition of "telephoto lens".  Please disregard this answer; Edgar Bonet's answer is likely to be correct. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22633/160017.

Comment: These lenses are often telephoto at the other end as well (as opposed to merely being long), and will be neither retrofocus nor telephoto at some point in the tranformation (that is, the optical center of the lens will be at the actual focal length). So, at the shortest focal length, the front group is divergent and the rear convergent, at the longest the front is convergent and the rear divergent, and in the middle the whole thing acts as a single, complex convergent lens. That's a lot of parts shifting around.

Comment: @StanRogers, I've expanded my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: No. It's either telephoto or retrofocus. Not both.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, this may be true for prime lenses, but the lens in question is a zoom lens.  As such, the lens configuration can change from retrofocus to telephoto as you zoom from wide to long.

Comment: Mmm... interesting. Do you have an example of a design that achieves that?

Comment: Can you explain how this switching from retrofocus to telephoto works, and why and how it affects the lens extension?

Comment: @EdgarBonet It's actually more than four independent groups in real life (especially if image stabilisation is involved) and no, it's not "overly complex". The transition from telephoto to retrofocal configuration can be explained by the relative movement of a single group in the simplest possible design -- the shifting of a convergent group between front and rear divergent groups, making the front and rear "group of groups" relatively more or less convergent/divergent. It's really a pretty elegant concept.

Comment: The "simplest possible design" is not optically the best design. Rather than moving a central "supergroup" in relation to two fixed divergent elements/groups, it's the divergent elements that move in relation to the convergent supergroup. When the front divergent element is farthest from the center, you are at the shortest focal length. Conversely, when the rear divergent element is farthest away, you are at the longest. When the lens is at its most compact, it acts as a simple multi-group lens (neither retro nor tele). The central supergroup itself may be varifocal.

Comment: @ZachGirod, please accept Edgar Bonet's answer.  My answer is incorrect. :(

Comment: @DragonLord -- if you believe your post is unsalvageably incorrect, you can delete it (thus earning yourself the "disciplined" badge).

Comment: @mattdm, I cannot delete it because it has been accepted.

Comment: Oh, the irony. :)

Comment: I don't wish to delete the answer, but I am willing to lose acceptance.  This answer nonetheless demonstrates a misconception in lens design, so it could be useful to some people.  Though it is technically wrong, it's not *obviously* wrong, so I will keep it as the linked MSO answer advises.

Comment: The comments, particularly those from Stan, are also invaluable and would be lost if the answer were deleted.

Answer (score 6):

With most zoom lens designs as you zoom in, the lens barrel and front element will extend, that is true.

But there are some lenses like the Canon EF 24-70 where the lens is fully extended at 24mm and fully retracted at 70mm.  So judging by the front elements, it seems to be working backwards!

And there are IZ (internal zoom) lenses where the front element doesn't move at all.

Any lens will have many groups of elements, some of which will be moving "out" and others moving "in".  I guess the simple answer is you can't just judge by what you see the barrel and front element doing, there is a lot more going on inside.  Some lens designs are very complicated.  I'll be very interested if someone can post a simple picture to explain how this particular lens design works.